# Issue creating a single query

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions, pgadmin-4

I'm having a bit of difficulty creating a single query.

From the CUSTOMER table (see attachment below), I need to write a single query that will display a count of how many customers are active and how many are not active. The ACTIVE column needs to have value of 0 for non-active, and 1 for active costumers.

Table and Columns that I have so far
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUgag.png]
ER Diagram
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/20X4p.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, just grouping by the Active column and counting the groups items.

```
SELECT
    Active
,   COUNT(1)
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY Active
```